# Basic coffeescript list comprehension with object

Tags: javascript, object, coffeescript, list-comprehension

Suppose I have an object with the following format `[Object object, Object object ...]`
where each object has the format `{word: blah, word2: blahblah}`

I know I can change the word and label to something else like this

```
({text: o.label, weight: o.count} for o in data)
```

However, I want to change it to this

`{blah: blahblah}` removing the labels and making each word in position of blah a key and each word in position of blahblah a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you can do it with a comprehension, but `reduce` works:

```
data = [
    {key: 'hello', value: 'world'}
    {key: 'foo', value: 'bar'}
]

result = data.reduce(
    (obj, item) ->
        obj[item.key] = item.value
        obj
    {}
)
```

Comment: actually when i try to use hasOwnProperty on it it tells me its undefined but I might be doing something else wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{word: 'blah1', word2: 'blahblah1'},
        {word: 'blah2', word2: 'blahblah2'}]
y = {}; for o in data then y[o.word] = o.word2
y
# { blah1: 'blahblah1', blah2: 'blahblah2' }
```

If you have `underscore` on hand, you could also use:

```
_.object([o.word,o.word2] for o in x)
```

though that is the equivalent of:

```
y={}; y[z[0]]=z[1] for z in ([o.word,o.word2] for o in x)
```